# How to add authentication header in JIRA webhook

Tags: authentication, jira, webhooks, jira-rest-api

I am writing some Java REST APIs which will be invoked from Web Hook configured through JIRA administration console. But, I do not see any way to add authentication header while configuring web hook in JIRA.

Without header, there is security concern in the sense that any one can invoke my Java REST APIs.

Could someone please suggest here how to add custom headers in web hook with possibly some example. I have already gone through Atlassian develper documentations but do not find any solution over there.

Comment: Have you tried the Atlassian Answers forum? You may get better help there, but maybe not.

Comment: While browsing Atlassian forum, this question was already posted by someone but unfortunately, there was no reply.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a username and password to the Jira Cloud webhook URL e.g.

- `http://user:password@mycallbackurl.com`

is ignored by Jira Cloud unfortunately. It seems that other Atlassian products do provide the ability to set a header / provide username and password for basic authentication.

Also see:

- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-31953
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12270170/where-does-the-webhook-arrive-from.

You basically have two options:

- You can add an API key or some kind of secret to the webhook URL. The disadvantage is that the secret could show up in your web server logs.
- Don't trust the webhook POST body (JSON) and pull the information from the API.

Adding the Atlassian server IPS to a white list would also make sense:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/database-and-ip-information-744721662.html#DatabaseandIPinformation-IPAddressrange.

Although it doesn't completely eliminate attack vectors since attacks can also come from another Jira cloud environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support to add extra header in JIRA webhook configuration. So, authentication header can not be added in webhook configuration.
To do the authentication, one way is 
1) Retrieve User information from incoming JSON
2) Make JIRA REST API call to check user's authenticity
3) Deny or allow further processing based on result

Comment: The JSON data in the body of the webhook can be send by anybody, there is no way to authenticate the user reliably. The username and id can be guessed.

Bottom line: never trust the JSON data passed by the webhook. I really don't understand why they pass this data.